# How to replace multi dimensional text javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't know the term of this case. I just call it `multidimensional` text replace. So, #cmiiw.

### The case

I have a `text` like this

```
var text = 'Budy: [expression 3 4 5]\nJohn: [expression 2 5 6]';
```

But I want the output is:

```
Buddy: 3 times smile, 4 times laugh, 5 times mad
John: 2 times smile, 5 times laugh, 6 times mad
```

I've try my regex query. But I don't know how to replace the number to be like that.

This is what I try:

```js
var text = 'Budy: [expression 3 4 5]\nJohn: [expression 2 5 6]';
text = text.replace(/(\[expression\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\]?)/g, "expression")
console.log(text)
```

Thanks for advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with your regex, you just need to capture the values of interest (`3 4 5` and `2 5 6`) into groups so that you can use them for replacement in the output:

```js
var text = 'Budy: [expression 3 4 5]\nJohn: [expression 2 5 6]';
text = text.replace(/\[expression\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\]/g, '$1 times smile, $2 times laugh, $3 times mad')
console.log(text)
```

Comment: is the variable `$1` till the end are the counter of the `()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const text = 'Budy: [expression 3 4 5]\nJohn: [expression 2 5 6]';
const regex = /\[expression *(\d+) *(\d+) *(\d+)\]/g; 
let result = text.replace(regex, '$1 times smile, $2 times laugh, $3 times mad')
console.log(result)
```

Output:

```
Budy: 3 times smile, 4 times laugh, 5 times mad
John: 2 times smile, 5 times laugh, 6 times mad
```

Explanation:

- `\[expression` - scan for literal text
- `*` - scan over spaces
- `(\d+)` - scan and capture digits
- repeat the previous two items three times
- `\]` - scan over literal text
- in replace, reference the captured digits as `$1`, `$1`, `$3`, respectively

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x = ["smile", "laugh", "mad", "xD", ":)"]

var text = 'Budy: [expression 3 4 5]\nJohn: [expression 2 5 6 11 20]';

let matches = [...text.matchAll(/(\w+): \[expression (.+)\]/gm)];

let y = matches.map(([_, name, numbers]) => {
  numbers = numbers.split(" ").map((num, i) => `${num} times ${x[i]}`).join(", ");
  return name + ": " + numbers;
});

console.log(y);
```